How to create a progress bar and then output information in each loop, using the tdqm library
The example codes:
from tqdm import tqdm
if __name__=='__main__':
    num_epochs = 5
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        with tqdm(total=500) as pbar:
            for i in range(500):
                pbar.update(1)

        print("epoch:{} finished".format(epoch + 1))

And the results is not what I expected.
console output
I've tried many methods I have found, but they not work.
The expected results is one progressbar followed by string "epoch: fininshed".

This should work.
from tqdm import tqdm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_epochs = 5
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        with tqdm(total=500, leave=False) as pbar:
            for i in range(500):
                pbar.update(1)
                pbar.set_postfix(epoch=epoch + 1, iteration=i + 1)
        
        print("epoch:{} finished".format(epoch + 1))


I would recommend something like the following, use description for the progressbar and reset the progressbar on every epoch this way only one progressbar will shown at any time.
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
num_epochs = 5
with tqdm(total=500) as pbar:
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        pbar.reset()
        pbar.set_description("epoch {}".format(epoch + 1))
        for i in range(500):
            time.sleep(0.001)
            pbar.update(1)

final output:
epoch 5: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 500/500 [00:00<00:00, 889.50it/s

Or if you really want to print the "epoch X finished" lines then the following can be used, but there is a minor problem with it: all the lines for every print will be before the progressbar and on a new line.
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
num_epochs = 5
with tqdm(total=500) as pbar:
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        pbar.reset()
        for i in range(500):
            time.sleep(0.001)
            pbar.update(1)
        pbar.write("epoch {} finished".format(epoch + 1))

result
epoch 1 finished
epoch 2 finished
epoch 3 finished
epoch 4 finished
epoch 5 finished
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 500/500 [00:00<00:00, 900.95it/s

